# htaccess redirect on error with broken link in get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect users to a nice http error page when they request a broken link. I would like this landing page to be a php page that gathers some info from the redirect and sends it to me in an email. The part i'm hung up on is getting the address of the broken link with either php or htaccess.

I was thinking it might be possible to get the link with htaccess and pass that as a get parameter to php.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://error.page.server/index.php?err=400&site=myweb.site.com
ErrorDocument 401 http://error.page.server/index.php?err=401&site=myweb.site.com
ErrorDocument 403 http://error.page.server/index.php?err=403&site=myweb.site.com
ErrorDocument 404 http://error.page.server/index.php?err=404&site=myweb.site.com
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.page.server/index.php?err=500&site=myweb.site.com
```

Here is the php from the server handling the error details:

```
<?php
// Get clients IP
function get_ip() {
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    } else if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ipaddress;
}

function get_page() {
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}

function get_site() {
    $site = 'UNKOWN';
    if ($_GET['site']) {
        $site = $_GET['site'];
    }
    return $site;
}

function get_error() {
    $error = 'UNKOWN';
    if ($_GET['err']) {
        $error = $_GET['err'];
    }
    return $error;
}

// Gather info into an array
function gather_info() {
    return array('IP Address' => get_ip(), 'Web Site' => get_site(), 'Web Page' => get_page(), 'Error' => get_error());
}
```

As of now the get_page() function returns null when htaccess redirects to this script. Instead of trying to pull the info out of the header with the script is there a way to place the page in a new get parameter via htaccess?

Something like:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://error.page.server/index.php?err=400&site=myweb.site.com&page= %VARIABLE HERE%
```

EDIT: Also note, this is the first time I've ever used .htaccess, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Do _not_ use absolute URLs for your error documents – that will cause an external redirect, and this is not what you want. Use a relative URL … then you will find all the info you need in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: I see what you're saying there. My thought was to use one server to handle errors for many many different servers, that's why its an external redirect. It is redirecting to a different server.

Comment: No, don’t do that, it makes no sense, especially not for 404 – the client will be told, _“hey, the resource `http://example.com/does-not-exist` can be found under this address instead, `http://error.example.com/something`”_ … and neither will answer with a 404 status code. (The latter would answer with a 200 OK by default – you could change that to a 404 of course, but this will still not tell the client that what he originally asked for does not exist.)

Comment: Ok, so i'll just have to add this script to each individual server, I guess I was being lazy in way.